# I can't get user authorization from Delicious

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, delicious-api

I'm creating an application in Delicious then I got client id and Client secrete from that application.
Use that client id I can't get the authorization key from it.

reference:[oauth](https://github.com/SciDevs/delicious-api/blob/master/api/oauth.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run as http request

You can send request like:

```
https://delicious.com/auth/authorize?client_id={YOUR_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/redirect
```